# Flutter Slider loop in BlocBuilder

Tags: flutter, flutter-bloc

I use a slider in a BlocBuilder which allows me to retrieve an initial value, but when I want to change the slider's value, I always enter the LightStateOn condition and my value takes the state.brightness value.

```
BlocBuilder<LightBloc, LightState>(
    builder: (context, state) {
  if (state is LightStateOn) {
    this.brightness = state.brightness.toDouble();
    return Slider(
      value: this.brightness,
      min: 0,
      max: 255,
      onChanged: (value) {
        setState(() => this.brightness = value);
      },
    );
    // );
  } else {
    return ...
  }
}),
```

There must be something I didn't understand. Can somebody please explain it to me ?

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, you're misunderstanding the concept of BLoC pattern. It would be nice if you share your LightBloc and LightStates codes.

The point is (in this code) flutter checks your condition `(state is LightStateOn)` **only when it builds the widget!**
we don't know when the builder method is called! So what do we do? we will use BlocConsumer. Then we listen to state changes. When state changes and listener function is called, flutter **rebuilds the widget**!

Greate, now if the state changes flutter rebuilds the UI. For example:

```
 listener: (context, state) {
            isLightOn = (state is LightStateOn) 
          },
```

I'd like to tell you that you need to understand that your bloc is going to control the value of slider so instead of `this.brightness`,  the value can be something like state.brightness (which you defined in your LightState). when we update the state in `onChange:` method. the way you wrote it might work but it's wrong in bloc concepts.

can be something like this:

```
onChanged: (v) => context.read<LightBloc>().add(UpdateBrightnessEvent(v))
```

If you share your complete BLoC code and screen I can help you more! and share a solution for you.